# How to access Beautifulsoup reserved words in an xml document in python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

How can I access a Beautifulsoup reserved word in an xml document in python 3?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = '<item><id>1</id><name>processor</name></item>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml-xml')
print(soup.item.id.text)
print(soup.item.name) # name is a reserved word in beautifulsoup
print(soup.item.name.text) # throws error
```

Name is reserved, but my xml contains it...

Comment: You could use soup.item.find('name')

Comment: Great! Can you put it in the Answer region as well, so I can mark it as correct solution? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Beautiful Soup [Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

Since you need to find a tag within the parent, you may use **find** which allows finding a single instance of a tag.

Thus you may accomplish as so:

```
>>> soup.item.find('name')
<name>processor</name>
```